# How do I move a contribution from one contact to another?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

The site admin accidentally assigned an Event payment to himself - how do I move the contribution to the correct contact? I understand that insofar as it's an event, it's not as simple as changing the contribution contact ID in phpMyAdmin.

I would think this would be a common request - any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

This [biz.lcdservices.movecontrib](https://github.com/lcdservices/biz.lcdservices.movecontrib) extension should do what you need but it has not been through the extension review process - use with caution.

> CiviCRM extension to support moving a contribution from one contact to
>   another. This can be done through the contact's contribution tab or
>   through a Find Contributions search result action.

Comment: As an extension reviewer I've just looked at the code for that one and it looks safe to use.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to correct this:

1. Delete the contribition and event signup and create a new record
2. Indeed change the contact_id in the database, you have to do this in every table which holds data for this contribution (I dont know which tables you have to check).
3. Use the extension mentioned by Aiden

Nonetheless to say that the safest one is option 1.